# Dynamic elements in ng-repeat; ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

EDIT: RESOLVED
My apologies, my mistake was due to something completely unrelated (logic in the ng-click event). But cheers!

ORIGINAL:
I hope all is well.

I have a block of HTML that is doing ng-repeat over an array:

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in arr">
    <button ng-click="event_lis()">{{elem}}</button>
</div>
```

and for the controller (in coffeescript)

```
$scope.arr = [2,3,4,5,6]
$scope.event_lis = ->
    console.log "Hello Stack Overflow!"
```

Some time passes, and there is a completely unrelated event that adds a new element:

```
new_event = ->
    $scope.arr.unshift 1
new_event()
```

The result? I'm seeing the new element render in the view, but for some reason the ng-click event is not firing at all. Any ideas?

Naturally this is for a very large project, so I've summarized for brevity.

Comment: can you bring it in fiddle ?

Comment: Should work, you need to fiddle it up for us

Comment: Thanks guys, was an unrelated issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is, I made a plnkr to reproduce it and it works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1QBefGy51Yc66C8LvP27?p=preview

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['first','second'];
  $scope.click_event = function(item){
    alert('hello '+item+' !');
  };

  $scope.addElement = function() {
    $scope.items.push('third');
  };
});
```

html:

```
<p ng-click='addElement()'>Add element</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click='click_event(item)'>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, turned out to be due to some bad code in my $scope.event_lis :)